# Spurious traffic hitting Keepalived

Tags: keepalived, vrrp

We use Keepalived (running on RHEL 7) to manage shared IP addresses on our 3 HAProxy servers. Each server has 2 interfaces, one with a public IP and one with a private IP. We are migrating from a pair of Kemp LoadMaster LM-3000 appliances.

We noticed that two of the three HAProxy systems are logging many lines every second for `bogus VRRP packet received on em2 !!!`.

This is 1 second of logs. I cut out the times and process numbers to save space.

```
haproxy01 Keepalived_vrrp: VRRP_Instance(haproxy::fqdn) IPSEC-AH : invalid IPSEC HMAC-MD5 value. Due to fields mutation or bad password !
haproxy01 Keepalived_vrrp: bogus VRRP packet received on em2 !!!
haproxy01 Keepalived_vrrp: VRRP_Instance(haproxy::fqdn) ignoring received advertisment...
haproxy00 Keepalived_vrrp: VRRP_Instance(haproxy::device) IPSEC-AH : invalid IPSEC HMAC-MD5 value. Due to fields mutation or bad password !
haproxy00 Keepalived_vrrp: bogus VRRP packet received on em2 !!!
haproxy00 Keepalived_vrrp: VRRP_Instance(haproxy::device) ignoring received advertisment...
haproxy00 Keepalived_vrrp: VRRP_Instance(haproxy::support) IPSEC-AH : invalid IPSEC HMAC-MD5 value. Due to fields mutation or bad password !
haproxy00 Keepalived_vrrp: bogus VRRP packet received on em2 !!!
haproxy00 Keepalived_vrrp: VRRP_Instance(haproxy::support) ignoring received advertisment...
haproxy00 Keepalived_vrrp: VRRP_Instance(haproxy::whiffle) IPSEC-AH : invalid IPSEC HMAC-MD5 value. Due to fields mutation or bad password !
haproxy00 Keepalived_vrrp: bogus VRRP packet received on em2 !!!
haproxy00 Keepalived_vrrp: VRRP_Instance(haproxy::whiffle) ignoring received advertisment...
haproxy00 Keepalived_vrrp: VRRP_Instance(haproxy::www) IPSEC-AH : invalid IPSEC HMAC-MD5 value. Due to fields mutation or bad password !
haproxy00 Keepalived_vrrp: bogus VRRP packet received on em2 !!!
haproxy00 Keepalived_vrrp: VRRP_Instance(haproxy::www) ignoring received advertisment...
haproxy00 Keepalived_vrrp: VRRP_Instance(haproxy::wwwdev) IPSEC-AH : invalid IPSEC HMAC-MD5 value. Due to fields mutation or bad password !
haproxy00 Keepalived_vrrp: bogus VRRP packet received on em2 !!!
haproxy00 Keepalived_vrrp: VRRP_Instance(haproxy::wwwdev) ignoring received advertisment...
```

`haproxy02` doesn't log any odd traffic.

- `haproxy00.example.com`: `em1 -> 172.24.0.200`, `em2 -> 192.0.2.32`
- `haproxy01.example.com`: `em2 -> 172.24.0.201`, `em1 -> 192.0.2.29`
- `haproxy02.example.com`: `em1 -> 172.24.0.202`, `em2 -> 192.0.2.24`
- `kemp00.example.com`: `em1 -> 172.24.0.48`, `em2 -> 192.0.2.59`
- `kemp01.example.com`: `em1 -> 172.24.0.49`, `em2 -> 192.0.2.60`
- "Floating" `kemp.example.com`: `172.24.0.50`
- "Floating" `kemp-public.example.com`: `192.0.2.63`

Note that `haproxy01` has `em1` and `em2` reversed compared to the other two.

The `haproxy*` systems are set to use unicast VRRP instead of multicast (sample of the configuration from `haproxy00` the others are exactly the same except for the changed interface name for `haproxy01` and a different priority. `haproxy02` is the `MASTER`):

```
vrrp_instance haproxy::fqdn {
  interface                 em1
  state                     BACKUP
  virtual_router_id         199
  priority                  100
  advert_int                1
  garp_master_delay         5
  authentication {
    auth_type AH
    auth_pass csvrp199
  }
  virtual_ipaddress {
    172.24.0.199/24 dev em1
  }
  virtual_routes {
      metric 5 to default via 172.24.0.1
  }
  unicast_src_ip 172.24.0.200
  unicast_peer {
    172.24.0.201
    172.24.0.202
  }
}
vrrp_instance haproxy::device {
  interface                 em2
  state                     BACKUP
  virtual_router_id         15
  priority                  100
  advert_int                1
  garp_master_delay         5
  authentication {
    auth_type AH
    auth_pass csvrrp15
  }
  virtual_ipaddress {
    192.0.2.7/26 dev em2
  }
  virtual_routes {
      metric 5 to default via 192.0.2.1
  }
  unicast_src_ip 192.0.2.32
  unicast_peer {
    192.0.2.24
    192.0.2.29
  }
}
vrrp_instance haproxy-csweb:haproxy::support { ... }
vrrp_instance haproxy-csweb:haproxy::whiffle { ... }
vrrp_instance haproxy-csweb:haproxy::www { ... }
vrrp_instance haproxy-csweb:haproxy::wwwdev { ... }
```

We know VRRP is working between the `haproxy` systems because we can shutdown `haproxy02` and traffic moves to the next highest priority system.

`tcpdump` shows the traffic we think is causing this problem. The `addrs` advertised from one `LM` to the other appear to be obfuscated in some way, since none of them are our real addresses.

```
[root@haproxy00 ~]# tcpdump -vvvvvni em2 vrrp
tcpdump: listening on em2, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 262144 bytes
13:54:09.672726 IP (tos 0x10, ttl 255, id 51772, offset 0, flags [DF], proto VRRP (112), length 56)
    192.0.2.59 > 224.0.0.18: vrrp 192.0.2.59 > 224.0.0.18: VRRPv2, Advertisement, vrid 1, prio 1, authtype none, intvl 1s, length 36, addrs(7): 127.73.197.82,124.192.126.111,231.25.226.215,113.220.143.181,197.101.63.203,152.246.226.65,46.55.62.80

[root@haproxy01 ~]# tcpdump -vvvvvni em2 vrrp
tcpdump: listening on em2, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 262144 bytes
13:54:36.739262 IP (tos 0x10, ttl 255, id 50547, offset 0, flags [DF], proto VRRP (112), length 56)
    172.24.0.48 > 224.0.0.18: vrrp 172.24.0.48 > 224.0.0.18: VRRPv2, Advertisement, vrid 1, prio 1, authtype none, intvl 1s, length 36, addrs(7): 120.18.52.8,8.96.198.173,44.237.204.205,99.139.163.15,10.76.116.67,163.0.175.114,121.54.183.104
```

So errors are logged on `em2` of each server for each `vrrp_instance`, but not for the instances on `em1`, and also not at all on `haproxy02`.

We are trying to stop these errors that are being logged because they hide more important errors and make tailing the log files impossible.

---

Separately, we also have `iptables` which I would think should be blocking the multicast traffic, but doesn't seem to be:

```
[root@haproxy00 ~]# iptables -L -n
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     icmp --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            /* 000 accept all icmp */
ACCEPT     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            /* 001 accept all to lo interface */
REJECT     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            127.0.0.0/8          /* 002 reject local traffic not on loopback interface */ reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
ACCEPT     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            /* 003 accept related established rules */ state RELATED,ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            multiport dports 80,443
ACCEPT     tcp  --  172.16.0.0/12        0.0.0.0/0            multiport dports 22 /* 203 allow internal sshd:22 */ state NEW
ACCEPT     112  --  192.0.2.24           0.0.0.0/0            /* 226 Allow vrrp from 192.0.2.24 */
ACCEPT     112  --  192.0.2.29           0.0.0.0/0            /* 226 Allow vrrp from 192.0.2.29 */
ACCEPT     112  --  172.24.0.201         0.0.0.0/0            /* 226 Allow vrrp from 172.24.0.201 */
ACCEPT     112  --  172.24.0.202         0.0.0.0/0            /* 226 Allow vrrp from 172.24.0.202 */
DROP       all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            /* 999 drop all */

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```